# i get failed to use passport js with sequelize ,

Tags: javascript, authentication, sequelize.js, passport.js

how to load the local strategy on the express ??

i tried console.log my passport stragetgi fucntion on my key/passport folder

here is on the key/folder codes

```
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'
import models from '../models'
const {
  Players,
  Clubs,
  Competetions
} = models

export default function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      function(email, password, done) {
        Players.findOne({
            where: {
              "email": email
            }
          })
          .then(data => {
            if (!data) {
              return done(null, false, {
                message: 'That email is not registered'
              })
            }

            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
              } else {
                return done(null, false, {
                  message: 'Password incorrect'
                })
              }
            })

          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    )

  )


  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);

  });


  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

    Players.findById(id)
    .then(data => {
      if(data){
        done(null, data)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      done(err, null)
    })
  })
}



// passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
//   done(null, user.id);
// });
//
// passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
//   Players.findById(id, function(err, user) {
//     done(err, user);
//   });
// });
```

i am i write long callback in the promise ?? 
0

1
I am building an app that requires authentication during login and for that I have used passport(passport-local). The app does not run for the login part and the last option available after removing all syntax errors is that the way in which I am using passport(as given in their docs) is for mongoose while I am using sequelize. Can someone please tell how to rectify my passport.js file so that it works fine for sequelize as well? (using mysql through sequelize; database is already populated) here is my passport.js file

Comment: Could you please share more info like error message, error stack, which lines it is failing?

Comment: Maybe following tutorial could help you: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql--cms-27537

Comment: You can reference the answer for this page <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017568/express-passport-session-not-working>

Comment: You can reference the answer for this page <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017568/express-passport-session-not-working>

Comment: You can reference the answer for this page <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017568/express-passport-session-not-working>